# nl command + number each line in a text file only from the third line

Tags: linux, solaris, shell, shell-scripting

I want to number each line in a text file on Linux/solaris by nl command

but only from the third line - is it possible ? and if yes please advice how ?

for example

```
line1
line2
1 line3
2 line4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f=filename
head -2 $f; sed '1,2d' $f | nl
```